# Icon from GWT tree menu item to the right.

Tags: java, css, gwt, tree

Is it possible to align the icon for a tree menu item to the **right** instead of **left**?
Like this :

```
item1 >
item2 >
item3 >
```

Where the ">" is an image. I am using standard GWT. Tried with both CellTree and normal Tree.

/Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Just realised this is a Google Web Toolkit question. I know nothing about Google Web Toolkit - but if they let you use normal CSS you can style any list in the way I describe below:

You can't do it with the standard list-style property, but you can definitely do it with background-image:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url('arrow.gif');
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put any Widgets as treeItem into the Tree. So if you want to put an item inside the tree which has the icon left just create a horizonal panel, put your text and the icon inside and then put the horizontal panel into the tree... (I know this sounds a little bit complex but it is actually really simple and you can do alot of other cool stuf with it)

```
    Tree t = new Tree();
    HorizontalPanel hc = new HorizontalPanel();
    hc.add(new Label("some text"));
    hc.add(new Image("http://tueffel.net/images/icons/icon13.gif"));
    TreeItem ti = new TreeItem(hc);

    HorizontalPanel hc2 = new HorizontalPanel();
    hc2.add(new Label("some text"));
    hc2.add(new Image("http://tueffel.net/images/icons/icon13.gif"));
    ti.addItem(new TreeItem(hc2));
    t.addItem(ti);
    RootPanel.get().add(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a `CellTree` with my own `TreeModel` which return a `NodeInfo` with custom renderer.

something like this:

```
viewModel  = new MyTreeModel( dirs.getRootItems(), filter );
treeDrives = new CellTree( viewModel, null, treeResources );
```

```
public class MyTreeModel {
    @Override
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo( final T value ) {
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<Item>( new ListDataProvider<Item>( dirs ), new DirectoryCell(), selectionModel, null );
    }
}
```

```
private final class DirectoryCell extends AbstractCell<Item> {
    @Override
    public void render( com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Item value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb ) {
    // my own html renderer ... 
    sb.appendHtmlConstant(value.toString);
    sb.append"<img src=\"" + value.getImgUrl() + "\" //>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new TreeItem(new HTML("Item Text <img src='path/to/image.png'>"));
```